# NX recompile error: Starting inspector on localhost:9229 failed: address already in use

Tags: webpack, graphql, nestjs, monorepo, nx.dev

I am using NX for monorepo project together with NestJs. After i run project everything works fien until I do some changes in files and save them. After webapck recompiles project it shows that it is started but has error in console "Starting inspector on localhost:9229 failed: address already in use" and GraphQL studio shows this error: `Cannot execute GraphQL operations after the server has stopped` for some time. After some time it starts to work again or after second save of files.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This happened because the app process is still open and listening to the port.
Normally when you close your app using Ctrl+C it should kill the process also.
I suppose it's a bug.

**How to fix it the easy way with NodeJS**

```
npx kill-port 9229
```

**How to fix it the not that easy way for Mac/Linux**

```
sudo lsof -i :<PORT>
kill -9 <PID>
```

**How to fix it for Windows users**

Open the task manager, look for the process/service using the port and end it using the right click.